# How to pass virtual member to list::remove_if

Tags: c++, list, stl, polymorphism

```
#include<functional>
#include<list>

class A {
  public: virtual bool isOdd(int x) = 0;
};

class B : public A {
  public: bool isOdd(int x) override 
    { return (x%2)!=0; }
};

int main () {
  A *a = new B();
  std::list<int> l {1,2,3,4};
  l.remove_if(a->isOdd);
  return 0;
}
```

This code produces the following compiler error for `l.remove_if(a->isOdd);`:

```
reference to non-static member function must be called
```

**How can I call `remove_if` so that the `isOdd` implementation of class `B` is called?**

I'm not looking for a solution that directly references `B::isOdd`. Instead, I want to have a pointer to the abstract class `A` and multiple (non-abstract) subclasses of `A` and use the implementation of whatever derived class the pointer points to.

Comment: `l.remove_if([a](int n) {return a->isOdd(n); });`.

Comment: you are mixing two orthogonal problems here. The error complains because `remove_if` expects a function that it can call (which `a->isOdd` isnt, and unfortunately the error is a bit misleading) and the second thing is `isOdd` being virtual, but it isnt clear why you need it to be virtual or why you think this would be a problem

Comment: `std::function<bool(int)> f = std::bind( &A::isOdd, a, _1 );
    l.remove_if(f)`

Comment: Thank you, @Jarod42, I did not think of using lambdas here.

Comment: @StephanLechner: Better to use `auto` instead of type erase type with unneeded `std::function`.